# bootstrap move and inheritance select window

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select

I have an input select in bootstrap3. How can I open select window under input form, I need it to move down. And how can I change color in input when select window is open?

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option>All</option>
    <option>Filter 1</option>
    <option>Filter 2</option>
    <option>Filter 3</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/udeL9m6a/

Comment: you'd have to make your own `<select>` functionality with javascript to style it.

Comment: @DLeh well, it seem too probably to customize it same way. I used angular-strap select and customized it through bootstrap.css'es classes> so the problem solved in part